# Nodatime + ASP.NET Core MVC + forms

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, nodatime

When using the Nodatime instance type for a datetime in my view model. It appears the model binding only works if the datetime submitted from the form is formatted exactly as: 2013-07-26T16:45:20.1234567Z

Which isn't very user friendly. I can certainly intercept the value while the form is being submitted and format it to match via JS.

I was wondering if there is a way to do this already built into Nodatime or some sort of setting that allows be to have Nodatime handle other values on the server side? I haven't been able to find anything except for perhaps a custom model binder which seems like overkill.

It would be good to allow values in the format of 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' for example.

**Update**: apologise for the delay. Using the code below:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using NodaTime;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("datetime")]
    public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] EntityDatetime e) => Ok(e.Value.ToString());

    [HttpGet("nodatime")]
    public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] EntityNodaTime e) => Ok(e.Value.ToString());
}

public class EntityDatetime
{
    public DateTime Value { get; set; }
}

public class EntityNodaTime
{
    public Instant Value { get; set; }
}
```

Results:

DateTime (these work out of the box):

```
2022-02-01 12:11             -> 2011-02-01T12:11:00
01-02-2010 12:11             -> 2010-01-02T12:11:00
01-02-2010 13:11             -> 2010-01-02T13:11:00
2022-02-01 12:11:34          -> 2022-02-01T12:11:34
2022-02-02T12:11             -> 2022-02-02T12:11:00 (HTML5 Date picker)
2022-02-02T12:11:10          -> 2022-02-02T12:11:10
2022-02-02T12:11:10Z         -> 2022-02-02T12:11:10Z
2013-07-26T16:45:20.1234567Z -> 2013-07-26T16:45:20.1234567Z
```

NodaTime

```
2022-02-01 12:11             -> Error
01-02-2010 12:11             -> Error
01-02-2010 13:11             -> Error
2022-02-01 12:11:34          -> Error
2022-02-02T12:11             -> Error (HTML5 Date picker)
2022-02-02T12:11Z            -> Error
2022-02-02T12:11:10          -> Error
2022-02-02T12:11:10Z         -> 2022-02-02T12:11:10Z
2013-07-26T16:45:20.1234567Z -> 2013-07-26T16:45:20Z
```

So it appears you need a minimum of the seconds. to have nodatime bind to an property using the built in model binders. So looks like will need a custom binder to handle something like: 2022-02-02 12:11.

Comment: "I can certainly intercept the value while the form is being submitted and format it to match via JS" - that's what I'd do, to be honest. I'd use a date and time picker, then format that value in Javascript, rather than asking users to understand different date formats. If you *must* do this server side, you can configure the serializer with different format patterns, but without any sign of the code you're using to configure the serializer, it's slightly tricky to suggest any changes.

Comment: Hi Jon! Long time follower of your work! Okay, thought I was going crazy, wondered if there might just be a configuration option. Think I might handle it server side, that way I can use standard date pickers. A lot of them will only visually format in the same format as the form posting format (HTML5 and Bootstrap date picker). The normal datetime component handles multiple formats without issue so maybe i can use that in view models instead.

Comment: Well you can replace the patterns used and specify a composite pattern - but I really wouldn't. What would you expect to do with "03/04/2022" for example? Is that March 4th or April 3rd? Much better IMO to do that client-side and consider the request as *machine-readable* data rather than localized text. And yes, you should absolutely be able to use standard date pickers - I'd expect *any* standard date picker to at least have the option to transmit the date in ISO-8601.

Comment: If you look at the HTML 5 control it appears to only do "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm" (developer.mozilla.org) which didn't seem to meet nodatimes standard. When I tried to use the control the request resulted in the value not being parsed. I will double check it, but from memory it was because the HTML5 control doesn't do the seconds, milliseconds and zone. I will just look into customising the model binder to handle it. Just prevents it working out of the box. But let me put a repo together just to confirm.

Comment: I suspect Noda Time is expecting seconds as well - but as I say, replacing the pattern is relatively straightforward... if you show us the code you're using. It's hard to help without seeing any of your code. (I suspect you should be binding it as `LocalDateTime`, given that that's all a format of `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm` actually contains...

Comment: Updated post with code and testing outcomes.

Comment: Right - so which of these do you *actually need to support*? While supporting multiple patterns if feasible, I would strongly advise you to try to make the front-end stick to a *single* pattern. Note that you still haven't shown us the code where you configure Noda Time.

Comment: There is no code to configure noda time. In the project that is how we are using it. Agreed the project should stick to a single format. For simplicity the format: 2022-02-02 
12:11 would be good.

Comment: If you aren't actually configuring Noda Time at all, I'm surprised it works even slightly. I'd expect you to have to configure the JSON serializer using `ConfigureForNodaTime` somewhere. You could search for that through your codebase to check? Which Noda Time serialization package are you using? (I'd personally still recommend a format that includes "T" rather than space, as it's more clearly ISO-8601. Note that the user should never need to see this.)

Comment: I'm not using JSON, the project just uses razor views. I will take a look at the time serialization packages but I wouldn't imagine that will help with forms and no there is currently no call to ConfigureForNodaTime in the code base.

Comment: Okay, if you're not using JSON then I've no idea how the binding works at all, I'm afraid. You could easily take a `string` instead, and then parse it with whatever pattern you want.